# Oauth access tokens across multiple Oauth libraries compatibility

Tags: php, python, oauth

Is it possible to create and store an Oauth access token with a php Oauth library and then from a python script access the token from the db and use it?

For further context, I have a fully functional python script using the python Oauth library that can create an access token and save it in a mysql database and finally makes some api calls.

However I am writing my website in php and what I would like to do is generate an access token using this [php oauth library](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/php/) and store it in the mysql db and then just use my python script to do the api calls.  But when I try to execute the python script using the access token generated from the php script, it get a 401 unauthorized error.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** - you just need to be sure you are using the same OAuth consumer and secret keys for both the PHP and Python scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will look into the problem further(newbie to oauth).  I just wanted to make sure that its possible in the first place so I woudldnt bang my head against a wall getting no where.